# left merge on date column act strange in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame as follow :

```
DateTime = pd.date_range('2011-11-23T09:00:00', periods=39774, freq='30T')
Emptydf = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':DateTime})
```

so the size will be `(39774, 1)`
I am reading the second data frame from a csv file which has the sale for some of the date,and the size and data structure is as shown

```
df1.shape   
(38375, 2)
```

and

```
df1.dtypes 

DateTime              datetime64[ns]
Sale                  float32
dtype: object
```

when I perform the following code :

```
df2=pd.merge(Emptydf,df1,how='left',on='DateTime')
```

I gate strange result .according to documentation the size of df2 should be as Emptydf but the size is: `df2.shape  (39800, 2)`
can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?
(DateTime  in both data frame is datatype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing DateTime `duplicates` in df1.

For this you could use:

```
df1.drop_duplicates(subset='DateTime', keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly  the problem